# Cannot get summer note in laravel vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, summernote

I'm trying to get `Summernote` with vue in laravel but it wont work.

### What I've done

1. install summer note
2. import summernote js file in `bootstrap.js`

> require('summernote/dist/summernote-bs4.js');

3. import `summernote` stylesheet in `app.scss`

> @import '~summernote/dist/summernote-bs4.css';

4. run `npm run watch`
5. added codes below to my component `ready` part

   import validate from 'validate.js';

   ```
   export default {
       data: function () {
           return {
               project: {
                   title: '',
                   body: '',
                   attachment: '',
                   projectclass: '',
                   deadline: '',
                   budget: 0,
                   user_id: '',
                   report_type: '',
                   csrf: document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content'),
               },
               errors: null
           }
       },
       computed: {
           currentUser() {
               return this.$store.getters.currentUser;
           }
       },
       methods: {
           add() {
               this.errors = null;
               const errors = validate(Object.assign(this.$data.project, {user_id: this.currentUser.id}));
               if(errors) {
                   this.errors = errors;
                   return;
               }
               axios.post('/api/projects/new', Object.assign(this.$data.project, {user_id: this.currentUser.id})).then((response) => {
                   this.$router.push('/projects')
               });
               Vue.nextTick(function () {
                   $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
               })
           }
       },
       ready: function() {
           var config = {};
           var that = this;
           config.minHeight = null;
               config.maxHeight = null;
               config.toolbar =  [
                       ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
                       ['color', ['color']],
                       ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
                       ['height', ['height']]
               ];

           config.onBlur = function(e) {
                   that.body = $('#summernote').code();
           };
           $('#summernote').summernote(config);
       },
       watch: {
           budget: function(newValue) {
               const result = newValue.replace(/\D/g, "")
                   .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
               Vue.nextTick(() => this.budget = result);
           },
       }
   }
   ```

### What I get

[image: one]

## Question

1. What and where did i make mistake?
2. How to fix it?